# What if app cache is full

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have to load many remote images in a screen. Titanium caches remote images and cache folder has limit. What happens if cache is full and I am trying to download remote images? Please suggest me what will the best way to approach this? Should I go for manual cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache is natively handled by both platforms. Cache directories are purged whenever the OS thinks it is needed. You can find documentation about cache directories for both platform in their respective documentations